# Is there a way of representing the minimax algorithm mathematically?

Tags: math, minimax, chess

I have successfully figured out how the minimax algorithm works for a game like chess, where a game tree is used, and you assign a value to the terminal nodes and propagate that value up the tree.

Is there a way to represent this algorithm mathematically? If so, how would I go about showing it?

Answer (score 3):

A simple google search gives plenty of results.

If you have a look at the entry in wikipedia for [Minimax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax) it has mathematical representations as well as some basic pseudocode and tree representations to help grasp the concept.

Proving it would be a matter of going through the regular methods of a [mathematical proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_proof) and would probably be a bit complicated.  It is far easier to discuss this by way of graphs.